C# / .NET 8 application optimize startup time
I have a .NET 8 / C# application that I've compiled using AOT and ReadyToRun (R2R) options to maximize startup speed. The application deals with opening a serial port, writing/reading data from it and then closing it.
After the first compile and run, I consistently see approximately 5 seconds, which I've chalked up to the application extracting some .NET assemblies/dependencies for first run. After the first run, most runs are approximately 200 ms long, but every 4-5 invocations of the application, the runtime is closer to 800 ms. I have timestamped my code inside Main and I don't see any differences between the different invocations, so to me this looks like an issue with some startup time incurred due to .NET (re)loading some assemblies.
How can I ensure the application always consistently runs at the average ~200 ms performance instead of the random jumps to ~800 ms? Is there a way to optimize this away?

Try using dotnet trace to see if any JIT work happens during the slower runs

Could also be an OS problem, like a anti-virus program, a lack of free RAM, etc.

There can be many dozens of background processes on a modern computer, any of which could be active or sleeping. Or even major programs (Outlook syncing?). Don't see how to get "consistent runs at the average ~200ms performance" in such an environment, you'd need dedicated hardware with no active 'distractions'.

With a "standard" .NET 8 program published as AOT (like dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release), there's no dependency left (in general), so no loading of any assembly (beyond Windows native ones). Is this what you're testing? 5 seconds is a lot. Do you have a reproducing project?

Maybe some large configuration files are parsed/evaluated on startup?

AOT and R2R may not necessarily improve performance in all the cases. If a program has too many assemblies linked, and if .NET is trying to load everything in the beginning, it may be slower. You have to use Lazy pattern, in which services are created only when they are accessed first time. Second, it may not be your own app's problem, as others have suggested, it may be antivirus, or your other services which may be using more cpu, you can however demand more cpu by running with elevated permissions and set higher than average scheduler.

Opening .. then closing. Then opening; closing ... can't be helping. Disrupting the environment.

What platform? Windows? Linux? Docker? What hardware?
